# Display paperclip image in Prawn PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, prawn

I'm trying to display an image from the database that was imported by paperclip. I have tried several things but I keep getting an error message that "File not found".

Here is what I have in my prawn config file:

```
def show_sample
    id_sample = Rails.root + @id_card_design.picture.url(:large).sub!(/\?.+\Z/, '')
    image id_sample, at: [0,900], height: 161, width: 250
    move_down 20
end
```

I tried the following to strip off the ?12345676 but it still doesn't work.

```
.sub!(/\?.+\Z/, '')
```

Comment: what is the result of `Rails.root + @id_card_design.picture.url(:large)`?

Comment: No such file or directory -/id_card_designs/pictures/6/large_image.jpg if I copy/paste that url into the browser the image is displayed.

Comment: The "-" at the beginning look strange. The problem is that the image function need local address and if it works in browser that it should be remote url which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using picture.path instead of picture.url

Comment: Thank you! This worked in development and was a much cleaner approach. open("#{@id_card_design.picture.path(:large)}"), at: [280,450], height: 161, width: 250

Comment: In my case the image is blurred in the pdf. Any idea what i should do?